# I have two activity in my android app. In my second activity i have a button for taking screenshot of previous activity

Tags: android, screenshot

[this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRdAw.png) I want to capture the screenshot of previous activity while i am on another activity.
if any one help me it will be very helpful for my application and for other also.

```
public Bitmap getBitmapOFRootView(View v) {

        View rootview = v.getRootView();
        rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap1 = rootview.getDrawingCache();
        return bitmap1;

    }

    public void screenShot(View view) {
       Bitmap mbitmap = getBitmapOFRootView(linearlayouttoggle);

       // linearlayoutmain.setImageBitmap(mbitmap);

        SaveImage(mbitmap);
}
```

**my manifest file**

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Toggle"></activity>
```

Comment: i think you have to take screenshot first then go to second screen

Comment: How can you take screenshot of something which is not on the screen ?

Comment: @Vivek Mishra this is what i want to know from you guys ..

Comment: not possible IMO

Comment: @farhan, rohit's suggestion is good one, you already take screenshot and then open next activity.

Comment: I think you should rethink this functionality. Maybe you could tell us what you want to achieve, so we can help you to implement it easier better way/

Comment: Activity is in background means went to onStop, you can only take screenshot of current showing activity on screen.

Comment: @farhan reffering to Rohit's answer, you have to remember to delete screenshot if you don't need it to be captured (while leaving second Activity)

Comment: I dont know how to take screenshots. But if you know it already. You can take screenshot save it in internal memory. Pass the path of the image to seconf Activity and access in the second Activity

Comment: And there is a chance that the entire saving the image might take some time. You can handle that using IntentService.

Comment: @Rohit Singh but i want to take the screenshot from next activity of first activity

Comment: What is the point? you can take the screenshot when the Just going to start. What are you trying to do In terms of UI ? Because it just does not make sense at all. Can you update the question with the UI of First Activtiy and Second Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: Assumption is that `MainActivity` is the first `Activity` and `ToggleActivity` is the second `Activity` (based on comments below)**

Your button could go back to the previous `Activity` and tell it to take a screenshot of itself. In `ToggleActivity.onClick()` add something like this:

```
Intent goBackIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("screenshot", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Adding the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` ensures that Android uses the existing instance of the previous `Activity` and doesn't start a new instance.

In `MainActivity` you override `onNewIntent()`:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra("screenshot") {
        // Add code to take screeenshot here
    }
}
```

Comment: i need a bit more info other than 'it is not working'. Please tell me what you did and what is happening. Also add your manifest to your question please (edit the question and paste your manifest in there).

Comment: @ David Wasser i haved mailed you on your mail id you can check that

Comment: @ David Wasser  from .Toggle Activity i want to take screenshot of .MainActivity

Comment: Sorry, I don't answer Stackoverflow questions in email. Post the data I requested here in the question and maybe I or someone else will help you.

Comment: I've updated my answer using `MainActivity` and `ToggleActivity` to help you.

Comment: @ David Wasser your answer worked for me .i just added these line in my manifest file               android:launchMode="singleInstance" and it works fine thanks man

Comment: Special launch modes, like "singleInstance" and "singleTask" should generally not be used. This is unnecessary and will likely cause you more problems down the line. Please remove that. That is the wrong approach.

Comment: @  David Wasser okay